# How to import code to Subversion?

Tags: svn

I use the Subversion on SourceForge, and sent some code via TortoiseSVN on WinXP, and it's a Revision 1.
When I changed something, I tried to send it as Revision 2, but I don't know how.
I was trying RapidSVN, eSVN, kdesvn, of course on Linux, but I have this same error:

svn: /svnroot/projects/****/****.kdevelop already existing, or something like that, where **** it's my project name.

What I must to do to send it as Revision 2 ?

P.S. Sorry for stupid question, and bad english.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the command-line tools to get acquainted with subversion. Then the tools will make more sense.

```
svn commit
```

in your checked out working directory

do:

```
mkdir ws
svn co file:///path/to/repo/trunk ws
cd ws
... make changes ...
svn commit
```

And it should say something along the lines of

```
Transmitted Revision 2.
```

Comment: No worries! Checkout the subversion docs, there is tons of cool stuff you can do with it! and good luck.

Answer (score 3):

In case you didn't know there's a good manual in different languages: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/

Answer (score 3):

After the initial code "import" you are referring to, you then need "check in" or "commit" your changes only; version control is based on differences between revisions, not whole file imports each time.

The [SVN book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/) starts off slow with a good chapter on the [fundamental concepts](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.basic.html) of source control.